# missing 1 required positional argument - Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

In my bas class I have following implementation.

```
def find_element(self, locatorMode, Locator):
    locator = CONFIG.LocatorMode
    element = None
    if locatorMode == locator['ID']:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(Locator)
    elif locatorMode == locator['NAME']:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(Locator)
    elif locatorMode == locator['XPATH']:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
    elif locatorMode == locator['CSS_SELECTOR']:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Locator)
    elif locatorMode == locator['LINK_TEXT']:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(Locator)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy")
    return element
```

I am picking the LocatorMode on line 2 from config class.

```
def fill_out_field(self, locatorMode, Locator, text):
    self.find_element((locatorMode, Locator)).clear()
    self.find_element((locatorMode, Locator)).send_keys(text)
```

When I call fill_out_field method in my test case, it is giving me error:

```
def agentLogin(self):
    self.driver.get(CONFIG.SITE_URL)
    self.assertEqual(CONFIG.SITE_LOGIN_URL, self.driver.current_url)
    self.take_snapshot(self.driver)
    credential = CONFIG.TEST_ACCOUNT
    self.fill_out_field("name", "accountId", credential['accountId'])
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/hassan/Documents/GitHub/poseidon/tests/base_test.py", line 155, in fill_out_field
    self.find_element((locatorMode, Locator)).clear()
TypeError: find_element() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Locator'
```

Comment: `self.find_element((locatorMode, Locator))` technically includes just the tuple `(locatorMode, Locator)`. Remove your inner parens and you'll be solid:
`self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator)`

Comment: @C.Nivs
Thanks a lot. It worked